# last character should not be space in string (Regex)

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

This is my regex

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 _\/-]+)$
```

I want - alphanumeric which can have "space" in between and " _ " and " - " and " / " ARE ALLOWED
Above regex works fine

But this regex can end with space <- "I DON'T WANT THIS" SO I ADDED -> [^ ]

final regex

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 _\/-]+[^ ])$
```

Now , another problem !

ALLOWED - AS I SAID "/" AND "-" AND "_"

```
dfcvg/
rdftgyhujn-
rsdtfyguh_
```

BUT HERE AFTER [^ ]
it is accepting any special character (I dont want this)

```
ftfuyf#
3245(
sdxcfhvjh?
```

Kindly help me `^([a-zA-Z0-9 _\/-]+)$` - i don't want it to accept space that is all or any
special character (except /-_)

Comment: I think you want `^[\w/-]+(?: [\w/-]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/NaUVEz/1

Comment: Just add a lookahead: `^(?!.* $)[\w \/-]+$` or `^(?!.*\s$)[\w\s\/-]+$`. If you want to disallow 2 or more consecutive spaces, then you need a solution form @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 0):

You can match 1 or more word characters or `/` or `-` from the start of the string, and optionally repeat that preceded by a space.

```
^[\w/-]+(?: [\w/-]+)*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NaUVEz/1)

```js
const regex = /^[\w/-]+(?: [\w/-]+)*$/;
[
  "ftfuyf#",
  "3245(",
  "sdxcfhvjh?",
  "dfcvg/ test test dfcvg/",
  "rdftgyhujn-",
  "rsdtfyguh_"
].forEach(s => console.log(regex.test(s) ? `Match --> ${s}` : `No match --> ${s}`));
```